# ASPX Passing Value to Previous Page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am new at aspx/javascript and need your help. I have a page, lets call it "A" that at some point is opening a new window "page B".

In page B I am showing to the users some lines of information and after a user selects the line that he wants (in Page B) I am trying to move to page A the selected line to process other kind of information.

**In page A**
I am calling a new window

```
window.showModalDialog("xscPopup.aspx", window, winSet);
```

I also have a textbox to receive the selected info

```
<asp:textbox id="textboxparametros" runat="server" name="textboxparametros" size="100" visible ="false"></asp:textbox>
```

**In page B** **xscPopup.aspx**

I already tried a few variants but I am always getting a javaScript runtime error.
My last try was:

```
var txtBx = window.opener.document.getElementById("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$textboxparametros").value;  
txtBx.value = 23; //Just to try passing something
```

**NOTE:**

This is a legacy application with many years and in many of the aspx pages was using the old "window.showModalDialog" (like you can see below) but because we will leave IE and only using EDGE I am trying to change the call without changing too many things.

```
var _result = window.showModalDialog("xscPopup.aspx", window, winSet);

    if ( _result != null )
    {
        document.all.txtCodDestino.value=_result[0].toString();
        document.all.txtDescDestino.value=_result[1].toString();
       
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you quite much have to dump use of showModalDialog. In fact, all of my browsers on my computer - it does not even work at all. The function does not even exist anymore.

And not only does Edge, Edge dev not support that deprecated function, nor does anything else.

[image]

So, the first step, the first goal?

You want to replace that routine.

There are a gazillion possible alternatives - (probably MORE!!).

But, one should settle on some thing that been around, has wide support, is wide used, and will work in just about any browser.

There are many, and even bootstrap modal pops could be used. But, I find them not all that great if you going to open another page.

I had by FAR the best luck using jquery.UI dialogs. There is probably a 99% chance that you already have jquery, and thus introduction of jquery.UI would not be much of a dramatic change.

And jQuery.UI dialogs DO have good support for popping up a external page, and thus again, this would work well in your case.

So, say we have a simple web form, and I want the user to pick a hotel. So, we have HotelName, and beside hotelname, a pick button.

that pick button will:

```
pop another page - grid of hotels to choose from.
user will cancel, or select a hotel.
the pop will close, and we then pass back the selected information.
```

So, say this markup, nothing special:

```
    <div id="EditRecord" runat="server" style="float:left;display: normal;border:solid 2px;padding:5px">
        <div style="float:left" class="iForm">
                <label>HotelName</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotel" runat="server" f="HOtelName" width="280" />
                <asp:Button ID="cmdSelHotel" runat="server" Text="Select Hotel" 
                    CssClass="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                    style="margin-top:7px"
                    OnClientClick="gethotel(this);return false;" />                
            <br />
                <label>First Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tFN" runat="server" f="FirstName" Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tLN" runat="server" f="LastName" Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>City</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tCity" runat="server" f="City" Width="140" /> <br />
                <label>Province</label><asp:TextBox ID="tProvince" runat="server" f="Province" Width="75"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:20px" class="iForm">
            <label>Description</label> <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" Width="400" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Height="150px" f="Description" ></asp:TextBox> <br />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" f="Active" Text=" Active" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" f="Balcony" Text=" Has Balcony" runat="server" TextAlign="Right" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
      <asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="btn-info" />
      <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn-info" style="margin-left:10px" />
   </div>
```

We load it up - however.

So, now we have this:

[image]

Ok, so when we click on "select hotel", we are going to pop a differnt page.

So, with jQuery.UI, we drop in a div to above page - (to hold the pop page).

So, we have this markup:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HReturnID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdReturnCode" runat="server" 
         OnClick="cmdReturnCode_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:normal" />

    <div id="myhoteldialog">
    </div>


    <script>

        function gethotel(btn) {
            myDialog = $('#myhoteldialog')
            myDialog.dialog({
                autoOpen : false,
                modal: true, appendTo: "form",
                title: "Please select a hotel", closeText: "",
                width: "35%",
                position: { my: 'left top', at: 'right bottom', of: btn },
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        myDialog.dialog("close")
                        myDialog.empty()
                        // myDialog.empty().remove();
                    }
                }

            });
            myDialog.load("HotelGrid.aspx")
            myDialog.dialog('open');
        }
```

We have a hidden field (for value passed back from the popped page).

And after a selection is made on that page, I IN MOST cases probably want to run some code in this page, right?

So, I have a hidden button - we click that button client side - we can think of that as our "please do something" after selecting whatever in the page.

So, when I click select hotel, the other page is loaded, and we now have this:

[image]

Now, the above is MUCH nicer then say a window pop, and you don't have the browser heading, URL or anything else (nice how jQuery.UI hides all of that junk).

but, there ARE some rules here:

First up, that selecting page can't do any post-backs. Hopefully that not too much extra effort. There ARE ways to allow post-backs, but they should not.

Also, KEEP in mind that the page is injected into that div. So, any selection button has to be either ajax calls (perhaps set session() values, and then you hit a ok button.

or, we can have the row select in this case directly call a js routine. Since the page was and is injected to the div, then the js routines called are on our CURRENT page!!!

So, the markup for the grid looks like this, and note the row button click event (client  side)

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table-hover" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"   ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server" Text="Select" CssClass="btn"
                            OnClientClick = '<%# "myrowsel(" + Eval("ID") + ");return false;" %>'                        

                            />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

so, when we click on a row, we get the PK row id.

And the routine called (in the main calling page), is thus this:

```
        function myrowsel(pk) {
            $('#HReturnID').val(pk)
            myDialog = $('#myhoteldialog')
            myDialog.dialog('close')
            myDialog.empty()
            $('#cmdReturnCode').click()
        }
```

so, I set a hidden field, close the dialog, and click our button to run our so called "run code after selection".

That code of course just sets the hotel name, and the description.

Say like this:

```
    protected void cmdReturnCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID");
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = HReturnID.Value;

        DataTable rstData = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        txtHotel.Text = rstData.Rows[0]["HotelName"].ToString();
        txtNotes.Text = rstData.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
    }
```

So, after above runs, then our hotel, and description is now filled out like this:

[image]

So, a few things:

For sure you really do have to dump use of showModalDialog. Most new browsers - it will simply not even work anymore.

And worse is often pop up blockers will still cause havic, so once again, all the more reason to adopt some "utility" that has dialog abilites. As noted, some suggest bootstrap, but for loading pages, I find the jQuery.UI dialog far more up to the task.

The only real issue I can see?

Does the target page you load require post-backs? I suppose if it does, then you could pop a iframe, let user do whatever, but the ok, cancel buttons would be able to run client side code in the current page. So, user could for example say in above, select a row (and we set session(), and then say hit ok, and we then run server side code which can grab/get/see/use that session() value set in that pop  form that allows post-backs.

So, above would let you pop + display another page. It will really come down to how and what was to be done in that pop page - and of course assuming that the page does not have post-backs.